# adding fractions class python

Tags: python, class, fractions

I have this portion of a class that takes a whole number and a fraction and add them together.

```
def __add__(self, g):
       whole_add=self.whole_number + g.whole_number
       numerator = (self.fraction.numerator * g.fraction.denominator ) + (g.fraction.numerator * self.fraction.denominator)
       denominator = self.fraction.denominator * g.fraction.denominator
       f=Fraction(numerator,denominator)
       return '{} and {}'.format(whole_add,f)

fraction_1 = Fraction(3, 4)
fraction_2 = Fraction(2, 3)
mixed_num_1 = MixedNumber(2, fraction_1)
mixed_num_2 = MixedNumber(1, fraction_2)
print(mixed_num_1 + mixed_num_2)
```

The outcome of this is 3 and 17/12, when it should be 4 and 5/12, I am not sure how to do this, I assume with an if the fraction is >= 1. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: First, I assume you're doing this as a learning exercise. If not, you almost certainly want to use the [`fractions`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) library that comes with the stdlib (unless you, e.g., need something faster, in which case you probably want to wrap up some optimized C/Fortran/assembly library).

Comment: Check after every calculation. When the numerator is larger than the denominator, adjust the numerator and `whole_number`.

Comment: +1 to @alexis. But also remember to take care of negative mixed numbers! Also, you probably want to return a `MixedNumber` from `__add__`, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [`fractions` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html), ou can just sum everything, then take the `int()` portion of the fraction:

```
def __add__(self, g):
    summed = sum((self.whole_number, g.whole_number, self.fraction, g.fraction))
    whole = int(summed)
    remainder = summed - whole
    return '{} and {}'.format(whole, remainder)
```

The `Fraction()` class implements `__add__` for you, you can just sum up integers and `Fraction()` objects and it all works as it should.

Demo using constants:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> summed = sum((2, 1, Fraction(3, 4), Fraction(2, 3)))
>>> whole = int(summed)
>>> remainder = summed - whole
>>> '{} and {}'.format(whole, remainder)
'4 and 5/12'
```

One little-known but handy factoid is that Python the `int()` type has both `.numerator` and `.denominator` attributes, that the `fractions.Fraction()` class makes use of. If you are *not* using the `fractions` library, you can make use of that yourself:

```
def __add__(self, g):
    summed = 0
    for v in (self.whole_number, g.whole_number, self.fraction, g.fraction):
        summed = Fraction(summed.numerator * v.denominator +
                          v.numerator * summed.denominator,
                          summed.denominator * v.denominator)
    whole = summed._numerator // summed._denominator
    remainder = Fraction(summed.numerator * whole.denominator -
                         whole.numerator * summed.denominator,
                         summed.denominator * whole.denominator)
    return '{} and {}'.format(whole, remainder)
```

Comment: Do you know why the `IntType` has these two attributes?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic: See [PEP 3141](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/); numbers have been unified and all have `.numerator` and `.denominator` attributes. For `int` values these are just the number itself and 1, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

One way to "fix" your version would be to deal with the improper fraction directly:

```
   whole_add=self.whole_number + g.whole_number
   numerator = (self.fraction.numerator * g.fraction.denominator ) + (g.fraction.numerator * self.fraction.denominator)
   denominator = self.fraction.denominator * g.fraction.denominator
   whole_add += numerator // denominator
   numerator -= numerator % denominator
   f=Fraction(numerator,denominator)
   return '{} and {}'.format(whole_add,f)
```

Although there are more efficient ways of doing this addition more directly.